# Could link-only answers from low-rep users be preserved as comments?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

Going through the recommended deleted queue I often see a lot of useful link-only answers from low-rep users who are unable to post comments. Sometimes I see a deleted answer on a question that has a link in it which helps a lot.

Would it be possible to add a button to convert these link-only answers to comments on the original question? So we'd have:

```
[Looks okay] [Edit] [Recommend Deletion] [Convert to comment on Question] [Skip]
```

Comment: Using the answer route to comment is inappropriate. Users without enough rep to comment should get more rep, not be allowed to bypass the system by creating work for a bunch of people.

Comment: Also, people unanymously choose the wrong decision for posts in the review queues _all the time_, I'd hate to see a bunch of useful answers that happen to contain links being converted to comments by the uneducated but well intentioned masses.

Comment: @TinyGiant people are already doing the work in the review queue, sometimes with the reviewers doing edits. They would need approval from higher rep users for these actions (like low-rep user edits). I can't see that as bypassing the system.

Comment: @TinyGiant that is a good point that they could be converted when they shouldn't be. Perhaps a character limit would help, or anything containing a code block not be eligible

Comment: It is bypassing the restriction placed on them by the system. They are not allowed to comment because they have not exceeded the minimum reputation requirement for the commenting privilege. If we wanted to have peer reviewed commenting for those users, we would design the system to that effect. Using the Low Quality Posts Review Queue in this manner would not be an appropriate solution, and would just stimulate confusion at the best of times.

Comment: @TinyGiant my concern is that we have someone find a question without an answer that helps them, then they find a link somewhere else that solves their problem, *then* they are kind enough to post an answer to the link that helped them in hopes of helping someone in the future. Then, we have high rep users come in and delete the answer. Surely we are losing useful contributions by this rule.

Answer (score 10):

In my eight years on this site, I can count on one hand the number of times I've seen a useful link in an answer posted by a user with insufficient rep to comment.

The negative outcomes of such a change (as illustrated by @TinyGiant in the comments, plus my own):

- Allowing lower rep users to work around an established rule
- Making more work for moderators as they are the only ones able to delete others' comments, and certainly a large number of reviewers will click that button irresponsibly
- It would elevate comments from being ephemeral clarification-seeking additions to questions and answers to something which would need to be reviewed.

The positive outcomes of such a change:

- When a low-rep user makes a good, on-topic comment in the form of an answer, it will be marginally easier for someone to move it to a comment.

I see the negatives outweighing the positives in this case.

Note that people with sufficient rep can move these kinds of answers to a comment already: copy and paste the answer into a comment, giving attribution accordingly.